# Reset AVR timer overflow register

Tags: c, avr

I have an [ATMega8515](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2512.pdf) and I am trying to setup a timer interrupt so that if a process takes too long it will shut off.

I setup the timer with:

```
void init_software_interupt(double time)
{
    OCR1A = time;
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 0;
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
    TCCR1B |= (1<<CS10);
    TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12);
    TIMSK |= (1 << OCIE1A);
    sei();
}
```

This works great. I calculated a clock second to be 7812 for an 8MHz clock and it works exactly as expect printing stuff once every second:

```
//Timer Interupt
int seconds = 0;
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
    seconds++;
    printf("in timer overflow: %d seconds have passed\r\n",seconds);
    in_progress = FALSE;
}
```

The problem is that I might call the function unlock_door() 750ms into the 1 second overflow count and it would only allow the operation to take 250ms which isn't long enough.

I've tried to just set the output compare register before I call the function but it doesn't seem to have an affect:

```
OCR1A = 7812;
unlock_door();
```

But it doesn't change the current overflow.

How can I reset the overflow timer before I call a function to ensure it will take 1 second?

Comment: why don't use a watchdog timer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using the compare interrupt, not the overflow interrupt. `OCR1A` stores the value that the counter is being compared to, and I believe that `TCNT1` stores the actual timer value. Try:

```
TCNT1 = 0;
unlock_door();
```

Here's a [good article on AVR timers](http://www.github.com/abcminiuser/avr-tutorials/blob/master/Timers/Output/Timers.pdf?raw=true), by the way. It's called "The Newbie's Guide to AVR Timers", but it works really well as a reference as well.